# Python 3 | Locations arround a point (lat/long)

Tags: python-3.x, geocoding

Is there a way to verify that a tuple of latitude and longitude values (for example, (-32.0321, -72.3213)) is whithin a R radius (in miles, kilometers, etc) of another tuple of latitude, longitude using some sort of api or function?

Comment: One again the over zealous reviewers have struck, if anything this isn't off-topic, but is a repeat of other questions that have been asked here and on other sites.  The OP probably doesn't know WHAT question to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html This site shows how to calculate the distance

And here is a pypi module for the harversine distance:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/haversine

Answer (score 0):

Try out [Shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/project.html#usage).  The units are arbitrary so that's up to you.

See this [example](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/192362/check-if-point-is-within-radius-of-another-point-with-shapely)